# PHP Function Return a Name Only It is Available in Database

Tags: php, function, return, return-value

I have a function to find a product name from Id. **If there is a product for that ID I assign that name to `$name` variable.** Otherwise I have a another code to run.

I have following code to do it. it works fine.

But I saw today **it is a bad practice return two data types** even it allows in PHP.

**Without return two datatypes how I do it?**

```
if(!findProductName($id,$con))
{
    // Some code....
}
else
{
    $name=findProductName($id,$con);
}
```

---

```
function findProductName($pro_id,$con){
    $sql="SELECT pro_name FROM product WHERE `pro_id`=".$pro_id." limit 1";
    $select_result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($select_result) > 0){
        $pro_row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $pro_row['pro_name'];
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: just return an empty string, like: return "";

Comment: @FrayneKonok Return a empty string or empty array? What is the best?

Comment: If `$pro_row` is an array then return array. Other ways you can return just true-false by assigning your `$pro_row` as a global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return empty string:

```
function findProductName($pro_id,$con){
    $sql="SELECT pro_name FROM product WHERE `pro_id`=".$pro_id." limit 1";
    $select_result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($select_result) > 0){
        $pro_row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $pro_row['pro_name'];
    }
    else{
        return '';
    }
}
```